# Pip and Python not aligning

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm on OS X 10.7.5

I am trying to get matplotlib to work on my machine, so I did `pip uninstall matplotlib` and then tried `pip install matplotlib`, but it said my NumPy version was out of date -- 1.5, and I needed 1.6.

OK, so I did `port install py27-numpy` and that seemed to work.  But I was still getting the same complaint when I tried to install matplotlib.

Now here's the strange thing.  When I do:

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
```

I get 1.5.1.  But when I do

```
import pip
pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

I see numpy 1.8.0 and matplotlib 1.3.1.  Why is my NumPy 1.5.1 in some places, and 1.8.0 in others, and how can I reconcile the two to 1.8.0 so I can install matplotlib correctly?

Comment: OS X already includes a version of Python which might interfere with what you're doing. What do `which python` and `which pip` give you?